# PHP activerecord exception : Base table or view not found

Tags: php, exception, phpactiverecord

I am trying out php active record, it's a great ORM,  however I am at a standstill.

I have looked around google, blogs, phpactiverecord documentation as well as statckoverflow for days but have not been able to come across a suitable solution to this problem.

I am able to carry out the basic CRUD (insert,fetch, modify and delete) operations however as soon as i validate an object property using a static $validates_uniqueness_of filter, i get

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ActiveRecord\DatabaseException'

With message

> exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or
>   view not found: 1146 Table 'test_ar.models' doesn't exist' in
>   C:\wamp\www\test_AR\AR\lib\Connection.php on line 325

Here is the code i used in full.

```
<?php
$path_to_AR = "AR/"; 
include $path_to_AR . "activerecord.php"; 
ActiveRecord\Config::initialize(function($cfg) {
        $cfg->set_model_directory('model');
        $cfg->set_connections(
                        array(
                         'development' => 'mysql://root:asdf@localhost/test_ar',
                         'test' => 'mysql://username:password@localhost/test_database_name',
                         'production' => 'mysql://username:password@localhost/production_database_name'
                        )
                );
        });   

/*
class user extends ActiveRecord\Model 
{ 

  static $validates_presence_of = array(array('username', 'message' => 'Please supply a username')); //this works just fine
  static $validates_uniqueness_of = array(array('username'));//this line causes the PDO exception   

}
*/
$user = new user(); 

user::create((array('username'=>'mike','password'=>'test','created'=>time())));
$user::create(array('username'=>'mike')); //cannot even reach this line because of the exeption
```

**References i have tried/looked at**

https://github.com/kla/php-activerecord/issues/274  (though i don't really understand what's going on there)

http://www.phpactiverecord.org/projects/main/wiki/Validations#validates_uniqueness_of

http://  blog.felho.hu/what-is-new-in-php-53-part-2-late-static-binding.html

as well as many others.

**Platform and php version**

I am using php 5.3.4 and using nightly build (May 8 2013) I have almost failed to get my head around this. Please advise on how to correct this.

Comment: If you [solved your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), please put the solution in an answer and not in your original question.

Comment: Apparently i don't have enough rep to answer my own question...

Comment: I've answered the question for you.  When you get enough reputation you can copy and paste my answer into your own, if you wish.

Comment: Alright then. Thank you Tim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been solved by the question author:

> After discussing it with a few developers on github. It seems this is a bug.
>
> The work around was to create a custom validator in the model
>
> ```
> public function validate() {
>         if ($this->is_new_record() && static::exists(array('conditions' => array('username' => $this->username)))) {
>             $this->errors->add('username', 'This username is already taken');
>         }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I had this error crop up today in a custom application, not Drupal.

my error was the exact same one.

however the issue was that I created the application on a windows server, then moved it to a linux based server.

apparently during creation the windows based application ran just fine, but threw the error mentioned after move to Linux.

THE ISSUE WAS:

--a database table that was created with a capital litter such as statePages... when it was created it was renamed to statepages without the camel case letter.

once I went into the application and where the app connected and drew information from the database, I removed the mismatch capital letter, and the application found the database table just fine and work like expected.

hope this helps someone else.