# Registration form update to MySQL PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm new to php and mysql. I have the following registration form that asks the user to put in name, password and email. The validation works and I'm able to connect to the database but I cannot insert into the table because I'm having a hard time updating the code from old MySQL to MySQL PDO. Here is the code:

Form:

```
<form name="registration" method="post" action="registration.php">
    <table width="400" border="5" align="center">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5"><h1>Registration Form</h1></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>User Name:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="name" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>User Password:</td>
      <td><input type="password" name="pass" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>User Email:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="email" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5" align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign up" /></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Here is the PHP and MySQL part:

```
<?php
// PDO connect
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "users_db";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    //echo "Connected successfully";
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }


    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $user_name = $_POST['name'];
    $user_pass = $_POST['pass'];
    $user_email = $_POST['email'];

        if($user_name==''){
        echo "<script>alert('Please enter your name!')</script>";
        exit();
        }

        if($user_name==''){
        echo "<script>alert('Please enter a password!')</script>";
        exit();
        }

        if($user_name==''){
        echo "<script>alert('Please enter your email!')</script>";
        exit();
        }


    // Validation and field insertion

    $check_email = "select * from users where user_name='$user_email'";

    $run = mysql_query($check_email);

    if(mysql_num_rows($run)>0){
        echo <script>alert('Email $user_email already exist!')</script>";
        exit();
    }

    $query = "insert into users(user_name,user_pass,user_email) values ('$user_name','$user_name','$user_name') ";
    if(mysql_query($query)){
        echo <script>window.open('welcome.php','_self')</script>";
        exit();
    }

    }
?>
```

Please let me know how can update after the "// Validation and field insertion" part.

Comment: You are missing double quote after 'echo'. It should be --- echo "<script>alert('Email $user_email already exist!')</script>";

Comment: Same for other 'echo'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its here for you but you need to read more about PDO:

```
<?php
// PDO connect
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "users_db";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    //echo "Connected successfully";
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }


    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $user_name = $_POST['name'];
    $user_pass = $_POST['pass'];
    $user_email = $_POST['email'];

        if($user_name==''){
        echo "<script>alert('Please enter your name!')</script>";
        exit();
        }

        if($user_name==''){
        echo "<script>alert('Please enter a password!')</script>";
        exit();
        }

        if($user_name==''){
        echo "<script>alert('Please enter your email!')</script>";
        exit();
        }


    // Validation and field insertion

    $check_email = "select * from users where user_email = :email";
    $check_email = $conn->prepare($check_email);
    $check_email->execute(array(':email'=>$user_email));
    if($check_email->rowCount() >0){
        echo "<script>alert('Email $user_email already exist!')</script>";
        exit();
    }

    $query = "insert into users(user_name,user_pass,user_email) values (?, ?, ?)";
    $query = $conn->prepare($query);
    $query->bindParam('1', $user_name);
    $query->bindParam('2', $user_pass);
    $query->bindParam('3', $user_email);
    $query->execute();
    if($query->rowCount() > 0) {
        echo "<script>window.open('welcome.php','_self')</script>";
        exit();
    }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks rehmat for the help and advice.

Answer (score 2):

This (your) code is not great, but using your example, instead of alerting a warning that the user(email) exists, just update the record for that user_email.

```
if(mysql_num_rows($run)>0){

    //echo <script>alert('Email $user_email already exist!')</script>";
    //exit();

    // 'Update' here if the email exists
    $query = "update users set user_name = '$user_name',
                               user_pass = '$user_pass' 
                         where user_email ='$user_email'";
    if(mysql_query($query)){
        echo "<script>window.open('welcome.php','_self')</script>";
        exit();
    }

} else {

    $query = "insert into users(user_name,user_pass,user_email) 
                        values ('$user_name','$user_pass','$user_email') ";
    if(mysql_query($query)){
        echo "<script>window.open('welcome.php','_self')</script>";
        exit();
    }
}
```

Check your variable names in your query.. ..and opening of strings with quotes.

Also, this code is wide open to SQL injection attacks.. ..and uses the deprecated mysql_* functions.

Consider revising the code to use mysqli_* and read about sanitising inputs from forms.

Answer (score 0):

```
//change your database name and table name
<?php
// PDO connect
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "test";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    //echo "Connected successfully";
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }


    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $user_name = $_POST['name'];
    $user_pass = $_POST['pass'];
    $user_email = $_POST['email'];

        if($user_name==''){
        echo "<script>alert('Please enter your name!')</script>";
        exit();
        }

        if($user_pass==''){
        echo "<script>alert('Please enter a password!')</script>";
        exit();
        }

        if($user_email==''){
        echo "<script>alert('Please enter your email!')</script>";
        exit();
        }


    // Validation and field insertion

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_email=?");
    $stmt->execute(array($user_email));
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  if(count($rows)>0){
        echo "<script>alert('Email $user_email already exist!')</script>";
        exit();
    }

    $query = "insert into user(`user_name`,`user_pass`,`user_email`) values (?,?,?)";
    $sql_query = $conn->prepare($query);
     if($sql_query->execute(array($user_name,$user_pass,$user_email))){
        echo "<script>window.open('welcome.php','_self')</script>";
        exit();
    } 

    }
?>
```

Comment: This gave me a "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]" error. I saw a possible way to fix it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17022001/php-activerecord-exception-base-table-or-view-not-found.

Comment: have you changed your table name or your database name correctly

Comment: put your database name 'users_db' in code and table name 'users' it will work